# AWS Translate | Asynchronous Batch Processing | CLI | describe-text-translation-job not valid command

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have installed and configure AWS CLI both my windows 10 machine and AWS EC2 Linux machine also have one AWS translated batch job in frankfurt aws region. I am following this document for to initiate the batch translation process using CLI. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/translate/latest/dg/translate-dg.pdf

Now, suppose I am using this sample command

```
aws translate describe-text-translation-job --job-id xxxxxxx
```

I am getting this error everyplace

```
[ec2-user@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ aws translate describe-text-translation-job --job-id xxxxxxx
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

delete-terminology                       | get-terminology                         
import-terminology                       | list-terminologies                      
translate-text                           | help
```

It only show 5 valid choice other than help but as per the documentation it should be more 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/translate/index.html#cli-aws-translate

why I am not getting these options

```
describe-text-translation-job
start-text-translation-job
stop-text-translation-job
list-text-translation-jobs
```

Comment: Which version of the AWS CLI do you have installed? It may be that you are using an older version which does not include "translate" commands. Usually when we see that error it means that the word immediately following "aws" is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

It was AWS CLI version problem only, I updated the version and now I get all the required methods.